# Using SQL to work out the average of some, but not all, records

Tags: sql

I am trying to work out the `SQL` to average a series of numbers, but only to include those greater than 0.

For example:

```
Field
4
5
0
6

SELECT Avg(Field) FROM Table;
```

gives 3.75. But I want it to ignore the 0 so the average is 5.

```
SELECT Avg(Field) FROM Table where Field > 0;
```

works but what if I have more than 1 field:

```
Field1   Field2
4        2 
5        0
0        3
6        4

SELECT Avg(Field1), Avg(Field2) FROM Table;
```

Using

```
SELECT Avg(Field1), Avg(Field2) FROM Table where Field1 >0 and Field2>0;
```

will not work

How do I do that? Note the numbers can be anything from 0 to 100

Comment: Will the fields always have same value? I mean: will Field1 be always 0 or 5? or it may be 0, 1, 2, 123 etc?

Comment: No - the numbers could be anything from 0 to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional expression:

```
SELECT 
  Avg(case when Field1 > 0 then Field1 end), 
  Avg(case when Field2 > 0 then Field2 end) 
FROM table
```

Comment: Perfect - I have not come across that before. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Just filter out 0 using the where clause.

```
SELECT Avg(Field) FROM Table Where Field > 0
```

Comment: Thanks - can you see the supplementary. I was trying to keep the question simple.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths   jpw beat me to that! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Avg(Field) FROM yourtable where Field > 0    ;
```

Comment: Thanks - can you see the supplementary. I was trying to keep the question simple.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the 0 to null like this:

```
SELECT AVG(IF(N=0,NULL,N)) FROM
(
SELECT 5 N
UNION ALL SELECT 4 
UNION ALL SELECT 0 
UNION ALL SELECT 2

) the_ns
```

Comment: That could work but I was trying to keep the question simple. They are not just 5s.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fake `AVG()` :):):)

```
SELECT SUM(Field1)/SUM(IF(field1>0, 1, 0)), SUM(Field2)/SUM(IF(field2>0, 1, 0))
```

I assume there is `GROUP BY` in the query